# Combine master and detail queries

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have two quite complex Oracle queries which I want to modify as little as possible.

For sake of explanation, we can reduce the first query to something like

```
SELECT A FROM ....
```

The second query is something like

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN T ON T.A = ? ... WHERE ....
```

The second query is currently executed many times, substituting the `?` with every value returned by the first.

Is there a general way I can nest the second query in the first, in order to obtain all the results I would get with the iterative procedure? I don't care about awkward syntax or awful performance; my main concern is to avoid as much as possible to modify the original queries.

Comment: Can you post the complete queries?

Comment: Not sure if this works: `LEFT JOIN t ON (t.A IN (SELECT A FROM ...))`

Comment: The queries are really complicated and would only add more confusion. What I'm really looking for is basically a syntactical transformation, in order to specifically avoid to understand the queries.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN T ON T.A = (SELECT A FROM ....) ... WHERE ....`

Doesn't this simple nesting work? If it doesn't could you paste complete or at least more informative queries and/or example data?

Comment: No, krsh, it doesn't work. You can't specify a subquery as a condition  in a left join. You'll get "ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery". If we can't see the complete queries, we can't help Flavio... :)

Comment: You are right, posted an answer in haste before I tried it myself :) Then as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752955/combine-master-and-detail-queries/21753768?noredirect=1#comment32903631_21752955 said  `LEFT JOIN t ON (t.A IN (SELECT A FROM ...))` might work, but this is all guessing since we cant see complete queries.

Comment: By the way this works in SQL 2008 R2, I thought I used it somewhere.., didn't check the join differences thouroughly enough though, sorry :)